# How do I incorporate an index value and a checked value in my xpath selector for an android.widget.switch element?

Tags: android, xpath, appium

I have an android screen with multiple switches on them.  Using Xpath, I need to identify which ones are enabled and disabled using only the index value to distinguish them.

I tried to use multiple 'and' operators to put together attributes but I guess I can't use two 'and' operators

//*[@class='android.widget.Switch' and @index=0 and @checked=true]

Comment: can you show how the html structure of element looks like

Comment: The full xpath selector looks like this

/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.LinearLayout[7]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.Switch

Comment: please read [mcve] and provide relevant information from xpath selector we get nothing we can't guess what in between those elements

Answer (score 1):

Here is how [Switch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch) from the Settings page looks like

```
<android.widget.Switch index="0" package="com.android.settings" class="android.widget.Switch" text="OFF" resource-id="android:id/switch_widget" checkable="true" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[916,1154][1038,1225]" displayed="true" />
```

It is not a problem to use multiple `and` clauses, however each condition must be a valid XPath expression which is not the case for your one. You need to surround these `0` and `true` with quotation marks as they're treated like normal [XML attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) of String type.

I would also recommend limiting your expression scope to `Switches` only as using wildcard will result into prolonged query execution time

Example suggested selector:

```
//android.widget.Switch[@class='android.widget.Switch' and @index='0' and @checked='true']
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)